# SwiftUI Popover doesn't detect Forms

Tags: ipad, swiftui, ios14

I've used this `popover` to show a form in my application, in this popover there is a `Form` with 2 sections, one with a `PickerView` and one with a`Button`; for some reason the popover is not detecting the size of the form like it does for every other view like `Text` and so on, I've tried setting the size manually but this is not the solution for my problem because I want it to automatically get the size

### This is the problem on iPadOS

[image]

### Also it looks very bad on iOS too##

[image]

### Code

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct FilterView: View {
    
    struct Category {
        var name: String
        var filterCategory: FilterCategory
    }
    
    @State private var category: FilterCategory = .event
    
    let categories = [Category(name: "Eventi", filterCategory: .event), Category(name: "Compiti", filterCategory: .homework), Category(name: "Voti", filterCategory: .grade)]
    
    var body: some View {
//        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(footer: Text("Seleziona la categoria che vuoi filtrare")) {
                    Picker("Categoria", selection: $category) {
                        ForEach(categories, id: \.filterCategory) { category in
                            Text(category.name).tag(category.filterCategory)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Section {
                    Button("Button") {
                        print(category)
                    }
                }
                
            }
//            .navigationTitle("Filtra")
//        }
    }
}
```

### Popover Code

```swift
Button(action: {
    self.showFilterView.toggle()
}, label: {
    Image(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3")
        .imageScale(.large)
})
.popover(isPresented: $showFilterView, arrowEdge: .top) {
    FilterView()
}
```

I'm using Xcode 12 beta and iOS/iPadOS 14 on the simulators

Comment: Form does not have own size and Popover does not have own size, so you have to specify some.

Comment: That’s not always the case, for example if in the popover i had ti put a TextView the size of the popover will become ideal for the text